# Ending a phrase with なく instead of a verb

Tags: grammar

> 私はいつもハーブティーをティーバッグでなく、葉っぱ{はっぱ}から煎れて｛いれて｝いる。

From Jpod101. The meaning of the sentence is clear (I always make herb tea with leaves instead of a tea bag), but ハーブティーをティーバッグでなく doesn't sound grammatical with なく instead of a verb at the end. Is it just short form for e.g. ハーブティーをティーバッグで煎れていなく?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ハーブティーをティーバッグでなく doesn't sound grammatical with なく instead of a verb at the end.

Hm, are you aware that 「ハーブティーを」 is the object of 「煎れている」?

You should parse the sentence as:

> 私は（いつも）ハーブティーを（ティーバッグでなく、葉っぱから）煎れている。

"I (always) make herb tea (with leaves instead of a tea bag)."

Comment: I thought that might be how it parses, thanks, but ティーバッグでなく is still throwing me off. Is this the で as in "method" or the で as in 「ではない」?

Comment: @Viridian It's the same one in ではない, but without the particle は between で and ない.

Answer (score 1):

Do you say "I always make herb tea with leaves instead of a tea bag" isn't grammatical"? Because it isn't "I always make herb tea with leaves instead of making herb tea with a tea bag".

The same phrase are often omitted in Japanese language as well as in English.
For example, 私はスペイン語を勉強するのではなく、英語を勉強したい is nomaly rephrased as 私はスペイン語ではなく、英語を勉強したい.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way - There are two options.

ハーブティーをティーバッグから煎れている。

ハーブティーを葉っぱから煎れている。

the でなく (you may have also seen this synonymous form でなくて） in this case is not trying to be a verb, not is it trying to end a sentence. It is indicating the speaker is rejecting one option and selecting the other.

So he is making tea NOT from a tea bag but from tea leaves. the NOT is the でなく

Other examples:

> 私は仏教でなく、神道です。
>
> I am not Budhist, I'm Shinto

or

> 朝ごはんは飲み物がお茶でなく、牛乳ですね。
>
> I drink milk with my breakfast, not tea.